# Solved --- ESP8266 with DHT11 / DHT22 Standalon -> problem with Arduino to flash the ESP8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266

before to come here, I've tried lot an lot of solutions found on the net and here.
The issue is:
After compile code (passed as good), I try to upload it into ESP8266 throu Arduino.
The result is:

```
« esptool.py v3.0 Serial port /dev/ttyACM0

Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____.....____

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/patrick/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.2/tools/upload.py", line 66, in <module> esptool.main(cmdline)

File "/home/patrick/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.2/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 3552, in main esp.connect(args.before, args.connect_attempts)

File "/home/patrick/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.2/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 529, in connect raise

FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error)) esptool.

FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header

_ le port série sélectionné _  n'existe pas ou votre Arduino n'est pas connecté »
```

During transfer I can see both Arduino (TX and RX) DEL blinking, and Arduino RX blinks the ESP8266 TX blinks also.  From there ... I feel like having good connection.

The pinout goses like this

Arduino - ESP8266

GND - GND

3.3V - VCC

RX+0 - TX

TX+1 - RX

3.3V - CH_PD/EN

According to [ESP8266pinout](https://i0.wp.com/randomnerdtutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/ESP-01-ESP8266-pinout-gpio-pin.png?w=487&quality=100&strip=all&ssl=1)

I tried to

- change the upload speed
- change the CPU frequency
- change the cristal frequency
- switch TX / RX  just i case I would plugged them on reverse
- updated the DHT driver and adapted the code consequently
- downgrade the ESP8666 driver on Arduino IDE from 3.2 to 2.5.1, to 2.5.0, to 2.4.9
- modify the upload.py file, line 66 and around

My ESP8666 did connect properly to the WiFi Network previously, programming it with Raspberry PICO and micropython.  From that, I'm pretty sure about the good working state of the device.

Below is my c++ code

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <DHT.h>

const char* ssid     = "BullFrog"; // Your ssid
const char* password = "Pr1on$J3sus"; // Your Password

WiFiServer server(80);

//Instantiation d'une nouvelle classe DHT
// DHT DHT (pin, type, count);
//  @param  pin
//    pin number that sensor is connected
//  @param  type
//    type of sensor
//  @param  count
//    number of sensors
DHT DHT(2, 11, 1);

double Fahrenheit(double celsius) {
return ((double)(9 / 5) * celsius) + 32;
}

double Kelvin(double celsius) {
return celsius + 273.15;
}

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
delay(10);
Serial.println();

// Connect to WiFi network
WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
Serial.println();
Serial.println();
Serial.print("Tentative de connexion au Wifi nommé ");
Serial.println(ssid);

WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
delay(500);
Serial.print(".");
}
Serial.println("");
Serial.println("Connexion WiFi établie");

// Start the server
server.begin();
Serial.println("Démarrage du serveur web");

// Print the IP address
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
int err;
float temp, humi;
if (temp = DHT.readTemperature(false, false)) {
  Serial.print("Température:");
  Serial.print(temp);
} else {
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Erreur lors de la lecture de la température. No :");
  Serial.print(err);
  Serial.println();
}

if (temp = DHT.readHumidity(false)) {
  Serial.print(" Humidité:");
  Serial.print(humi);
  Serial.println();
} else {
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Erreur lors de la lecture de l humidité relative. No :");
  Serial.print(err);
  Serial.println();
}
WiFiClient client = server.available();
client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
client.println("Connection: close"); 
client.println("Refresh: 5");  
client.println();
client.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
client.println("<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>");
client.println("<head>\n<meta charset='UTF-8'>");
client.println("<title>ESP8266 Température & Humidité DHT11</title>");
client.println("</head>\n<body>");
client.println("<H2>Capteurs ESP8266 & DHT11</H2>");
client.println("<H3>Humidité / Température</H3>");
client.println("<pre>");
client.print("Humidité (%)       : ");
client.println((float)humi, 2);
client.print("Température (°C)  : ");
client.println((float)temp, 2);
client.print("Température (°F)  : ");
client.println(Fahrenheit(temp), 2);
client.print("Température (°K)  : ");
client.println(Kelvin(temp), 2);
client.println("</pre>");
client.println("<H3>Revenez nous voir!</H3>");
client.print("</body>\n</html>");
//  delay(DHT11_RETRY_DELAY); //delay for reread
}
```

I want to use [this kit](https://www.cafr.ebay.ca/itm/194629833476?_trkparms=amclksrc%3DITM%26aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20160908105057%26meid%3Db41a34f55bb84d0ba0d4d8f17dc2d02f%26pid%3D100675%26rk%3D13%26rkt%3D15%26sd%3D133471810730%26itm%3D194629833476%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2380057%26brand%3DUnbranded&_trksid=p2380057.c100675.m4236&_trkparms=pageci%3A338c6fb3-226b-11ed-89f3-825ac7fa8724%7Cparentrq%3Ac7b573f31820a45b4a608fddfffda518%7Ciid%3A1) in standalone

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.elec-cafe.com/esp8266-temperature-humidity-webserver-with-a-dht11-sensor/) (among others)

Thanks for your attention and help.

Comment: is the esp8266 in flashing mode? if you want to reach the esp8266 from computer over the USB chip of the Arduino, you have to wire RX to RX and TX to TX (because the USB chip is wired to the MCU RX to TX)

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to program your ESP-01 with a simple Blink sketch, just to confirm the ESP-01 is ok.

These are examples from the same website you reference:

- https://www.elec-cafe.com/tag/esp8266-flasher/
- https://www.elec-cafe.com/esp8266-esp-01-firmware-update/

Also, the ESP8266 requires a good amount for power for WiFi transmit.  Sometimes it help to use separate power supply and add 470uF or 1000uF capacitor across the VCC and GND of the ESP chip.

I hope this might help you to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in coding but in wiring.

Remember that (with ESP8266-01) :

pin 1 as GND  (from left to right  1,2,3,4) on the row near to the middle of board

pins 5 as VCC  (from right to left 5,6,7,8) on the row near to the ridge of board

[image: Uploading connection]

pins 5 and 7 must be permanently connected
for loading code into ESP8266-01:  pins 1 and 3 must be connected for the uploading time duration.

Once everything is uploaded, come back to the using position (uplug 1 - 3) like this:
[image: Using connections]